# Cypress: selecting and iterating over R shiny selectizeInput elements

Tags: r, shiny, cypress, selectize.js

I am currently learning some very basic JS and Cypress in order to be able to write some UI test for the shiny R markdown application I am developing (very new to this!!). I have managed to write a simple test that asserts that a given value is selected by default when the app starts up. However, I would like to be able to select a specific element and more importantly, loop over the entire list of elements available in order to assert that the output is as expected.

I'm stuck figuring out how to select a specific element from the dropdown and also don't know how to implement a loop yet. Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Here is a simple shiny app that contains only a dropdown with 3 options (`app.R` file) as I cannot share the original code due to proprietary reasons:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectizeInput(inputId = 'element1', label = "Test input", 
                choices = c('descriptive', 'comparative', 'neutral'),
                selected = 'descriptive')
 
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In my simple UI test, I have managed to write the assertions similar to this:

```js
cy.get('select#element1 option:selected')
.should('have.value', 'descriptive')
```

But when I use the web inspector to inspect the structure of the `selectizeInput`, I don't understand why the options are not listed as select options. That seems to be the reason for why I cannot use something like `cy.get('select#element1').select('comparative')` to select a different value from the dropdown. I thought maybe the other options were "hidden", but I then found them in a separate div further down in the DOM:

[image]

I'm really just starting to learn all of this, so any pointers would be super helpful. Even just to help me google the right things, because googling how to work with select elements in cypress was apparently not the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eq()` command if you want to select any items from the dropdown:

```js
//Click to open the dropdown
cy.get('div.option').eq(1).click() //selects comparative
```

You can also use a combination of text and selector using `contains()` and select the item from drop-down:

```js
//Click to open the dropdown
cy.contains('div.option', 'neutral').click() //selects neutral
```

You can also use the `filter()` command:

```js
//Click to open the dropdown
cy.get('div.option').filter(':contains("neutral")').click() //selects neutral
```

If you want to loop through the elements and then select you can do something like:

1. Using the index Position

```js
//Click to open the dropdown
cy.get('div.option').each(($ele, index) => {
  if (index == 1) {
    cy.wrap($ele).eq(index).click()
  }
})
```

2. Using the element text

```js
//Click to open the dropdown
cy.get('div.option').each(($ele, index) => {
  if($ele.text() == "comparative") {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Alapan, thank you for your answer. I can't get it to work because I keep getting the error that div.option cannot be found. I wonder if your code could work if specified the element (e.g. select#element1) and used .next() as suggested by Paolo?

Comment: Run this command ince you have the drop down list opened in the webpage.

Comment: I've tried `cy.get('select#element1').click().cy.get('div.option').eq(1).click()` and `cy.get('select#element1').next().click(). cy.get('div.option').eq(1).click()` and neither worked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Component libraries often enhance the select control in order to give a better look, additional features like multi-select. The plain HTML5 select is limited in how you can style and control it.

In the case of Shiny library, they have added both a `<select>` to hold the value plus a set of nested `<div>` to provide the enhancements (the next element block after `<select>`).

The `<select>` has `style="display: none;"` which means the user cannot interact with it directly, but it is updated in the javascript event handlers.

Doing e2e tests we want interact as a user would, but test the hidden `<select>` value since this is what is used by the R framework.

```js
// Test the initial value of hidden select
cy.get('select#element1')
  .should('have.value', 'descriptive')
  .find('option')
  .should('have.length', 1)             // only one option on the select

cy.get('select#e1')
  .next()                        // access the UI block
  .click()                       // open the "select"
  .contains('comparative')       // chose an option
  .click()

// Test the new value of hidden select
cy.get('select#e1')
  .should('have.value', 'comparative')
  .find('option')
  .should('have.length', 1)      // still only one option
```

**Looping**

```js
// Test the initial value of hidden select
cy.get('select#element1')
  .should('have.value', 'descriptive')
  .find('option')
  .should('have.length', 1)             // only one option on the select

const choices = ['descriptive', 'comparative', 'neutral']

choices.forEach(choice => {
 
  cy.get('select#e1')
    .next()                        // access the UI block
    .click()                       // open the "select"
    .contains(choice)              // chose this choice
    .click()

  // Test the new value of hidden select
  cy.get('select#e1')
    .should('have.value', choice)
})
```

Comment: `'select#e1` should be `'select#element1'`

Comment: Hi Paolo. Thank you for your answer and also for explaining how component libraries work under the hood. This really helped me to understand better. I also successfully managed to select and click a different option in the dropdown. Could you also explain how I would loop over all options with your approach?

Comment: Depending on the aim of the looping, with a known set of options use an array forEach.

Comment: The set of options will be variable, but this already helps. I will read up on loops first.